# Essential singularities of $z(\exp(1/z)-1)^{-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm studying for a qualifying exam, so I'm trying to find *efficient* ways to answer difficult questions.  Here's an example:

Find and classify the singularities of

$$
f(z)=\frac{z}{e^{1/z}-1}
$$ Intuitively, $f$ should have an essential singularity at $z=0$ and $z=\infty$.  Is there an easy way to justify this? Computing the Laurent series seems difficult at first glance - or am I just being a wuss?

Comment: Here's a hint for essential singularities, in the form of a corollary: If $f(z)$ has an essential singularity at $z_0$, then it follows that $\lim_{z \to z_0} |f(z)| \neq +\infty$. That is, this limit does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems it is certainly continuous at each point except $z=0$ and $\{e^{1/z}=1\}$. $\{e^{1/z}=1\}$ will give you poles, not an essential singularities. It remains to show that $z=0$ gives an essential singularity. Certainly it is an isolated point of discontinuity, so one need only show it is neither a pole, nor a removable discontinuity. To do so, find points $z_n$ arbitrarily close to $0$ with $|f(z_n)|$ bounded, and separately, show $f$ cannot have a limit at zero.

**Edit** : an alert user has pointed out that $z=0$ is not even an isolated singularity! Therefore, *a priori* it cannot be an essential singularity. So there cannot be any essential singularities of this function.

Comment: Actually, $z=0$ is *not* an isolated singularity. Points where $z = 1/(2\pi i n)$ are poles for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, and these poles tend to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Very good point! So there cannot be any essential singularities!

Comment: @mrf and eric: so, because $z=0$ is a limit point of a set of isolated singularities, it cannot be an isolated singularity.  So what is it...?

Comment: There may be classifications of non-isolated singularities, but I have not learned them. In my complex course, we learned that singularities which are isolated can be classified into exactly three types.

Comment: @icurays1 You can describe it an *accumulation point of poles*. Generally, there is no need to invent a term for an object about which there is little to be said. The reason we have classification of isolated singularities, with special names for their types, is that there are useful theorems about such points.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that $z=0$ could be what is called a cluster point, a type of nonisolated singularity. So yes, you might not really need the Laurent series expansion, given that it does not exist. Here's the following link (jump to the section on nonisolated singularities): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_singularity#Nonisolated_singularities

I hope this helps.